# Add random/uneven spacing between pixel blocks in an HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this code that takes an image and divides it into blocks with a size of blockSize, then deletes the surrounding pixels and spaces them out by a spacing defined by spacing. This creates a uniform split, but I want to add some randomness to the spacing to distribute the blocks unevenly (controlled by variance variable).

Bonus answer: Also add some randomness to the blockSize to make some blocks larger than others. This is my current code:

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
const ctx = ref.current.getContext("2d")!
const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ref.current.width, ref.current.height)
const pixels = imgData.data

let blockSize = 5
let spacing = 70
let variance = 50

for (let row = 0; row < imgData.height; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < imgData.width; col++) {
        const i = (row * imgData.width + col) * 4
        let r = pixels[i]
        let g = pixels[i+1]
        let b = pixels[i+2]
        let a = pixels[i+3]
        const adjustedSpacing = spacing // Add randomness?
        const blockRow = Math.floor(row / (blockSize + adjustedSpacing))
        const blockCol = Math.floor(col / (blockSize + adjustedSpacing))
        const blockRowPixel = blockRow * (blockSize + adjustedSpacing)
        const blockColPixel = blockCol * (blockSize + adjustedSpacing)

        const withinBlockRow = row >= blockRowPixel && row < blockRowPixel + blockSize
        const withinBlockCol = col >= blockColPixel && col < blockColPixel + blockSize
        if (withinBlockRow && withinBlockCol) {
            pixels[i] = r
            pixels[i+1] = g
            pixels[i+2] = b
            pixels[i+3] = a
        } else {
            pixels[i] = 0
            pixels[i+1] = 0
            pixels[i+2] = 0
            pixels[i+3] = 0
        }
    }
}
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0)
```

This was my attempted solution, but it doesn't work. It destroys the blocks:

```
const adjustedSpacing = Math.floor(Math.random() * variance) + spacing
```

Comment: draw a mask (white pixels on black background) using randomly drawn rectangles (however you like), then erase image pixels that aren't in the mask. you can draw each mask box with some randomness in its size and position, while still being in a grid.

Comment: Do you know how I can prevent the rectangles from overlapping? (Preferably also maintain the same spacing between each)

Comment: just calculate their positions such that they do not overlap...? if you demand the same space between adjacent rectangles, their respective distances would be related. this is merely a programming problem, i.e. requires practice, and perhaps asking on a forum for beginners. SO seems the wrong place for that. [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]

Comment: Thanks, I solved the original question using your mask method. I will still need to figure out the random sizing, calculating the positions so they don't overlap is harder than it seems. Thanks though, your comment helped!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to the problem using the mask method. We draw a mask with black bg and white squares with the random spacing applied, then use the mask to edit the pixels in the original canvas.

```
// Draw point mask
const pointMask = document.createElement("canvas")
pointMask.width = ref.current.width 
pointMask.height = ref.current.height
const pointCtx = pointMask.getContext("2d")!
pointCtx.fillStyle = "#000000"
pointCtx.fillRect(0, 0, pointMask.width, pointMask.height)

let adjustedSpacing = spacing
for (let x = adjustedSpacing; x < pointMask.width; x += blockSize + adjustedSpacing + (functions.random(seed+x) * variance)) {
    for (let y = adjustedSpacing; y < pointMask.height; y += blockSize + adjustedSpacing + (functions.random(seed+y) * variance)) {
        let x2 = x + blockSize
        const length = x2 - x
        pointCtx.beginPath()
        pointCtx.moveTo(x, y)
        pointCtx.lineTo(x2, y)
        pointCtx.lineTo(x2, y - length)
        pointCtx.lineTo(x, y - length)
        pointCtx.closePath()
        pointCtx.fillStyle = "#ffffff"
        pointCtx.fill()
    }
}
const pointData = pointCtx.getImageData(0, 0, pointMask.width, pointMask.height)
const pointPixels = pointData.data

// Apply the mask
for (let i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 4) {
    let r = pixels[i]
    let g = pixels[i+1]
    let b = pixels[i+2]
    let a = pixels[i+3]
    if (pointPixels[i] === 255 && pointPixels[i+1] === 255 && pointPixels[i+2] === 255) {
       pixels[i] = r
       pixels[i+1] = g
       pixels[i+2] = b
       pixels[i+3] = a
    } else {
       pixels[i] = 0
       pixels[i+1] = 0
       pixels[i+2] = 0
       pixels[i+3] = 0
    }
}
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0)
```